# LINQ join and group

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, nhibernate

I'm new to LINQ, and I'm trying to convert this SQL query into its LINQ equivalent:

```
select S.*
from Singles S
join (
    select max(SingleId) as SingleId
    from Single 
    group by ArtistId) S2 on S2.SingleId = S.SingleId
order by Released desc
```

The table looks like this:

```
 -----------
| Singles   |
|-----------|
| SingleID  |
| ArtistId  |
| Released  |
| Title     |
| .....     |
 -----------
```

and so on...
And contains for example these items:

```
SingleID   ArtistID    Released    Title
1          1           2011-05-10  Title1
2          1           2011-05-10  Title2
3          2           2011-05-10  Title3
4          3           2011-05-10  Title4
5          4           2011-05-10  Title5
6          2           2011-05-10  Title6
7          3           2011-05-10  Title7
8          5           2011-05-10  Title8
9          6           2011-05-10  Title9
```

So I'm trying to get the latest singles, but only one per artist. Could anyone help me? :)
Maybe there's even a better way to write the query?

### Update:

To answer the questions posted in the comments:
We're using Microsoft SQL Server, and LINQ to NHibernate.

Here's a sample that we're using right now, that returns the latest singles, without grouping by artistid:

```
public Single[] GetLatest()
{
    IQueryable<Single> q;
    q = from s in _sess.Query<Single>()
        where s.State == State.Released
        orderby s.Released descending
        select s;

    return q.Take(20).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Is it for SQL-Server or other DBMS ?

Comment: What are you working with? LINQ to SQL? LINQ to Objects? Please show us the code you already have.

Comment: Updated to answer your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
var firstSingles = Singles.GroupBy(x => x.ArtistId)
                          .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Released).First())
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: This gives me an exception.

[InvalidOperationException: Code supposed to be unreachable]
   System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(....

Comment: @AmITheRWord: After some quick research it seems that `GroubBy` in combinations with other operators might be the cause of the problem (also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069925/group-by-using-linq-with-nhibernate-3-0) - it's a guessing game how to rewrite the query to make it work.

Comment: Thanks! Now I can move on, at least. :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
var query = from s in db.Singles
            group s by s.ArtistID into sg
            let firstSingle = sg.OrderByDescending(r => r.SingleID).FirstOrDefault()
            select new
            {
              ArtistID = sg.Key,
              SingleID = firstSingle.SingleID,
              Released = firstSingle.Released,
              Title = firstSingle.Title,
            }
```

Comment: you can use the `let` keyword to define a range variable in your query: `let firstSingle = sg.OrderByDescending(r => r.SingleID).First()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
singles
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.SingleID)
    .GroupBy(s => s.SingerID, (id, s) => new
    {
         SingleID = id,
         Title = s.First().Title
    });
```